# Want to add Test paper using the Exam class in my memoir class book.

Tags: exam, standalone

I am publishing a book in Lecture form. In which every section is with concepts and problem solving with assignment. And in the end, there is a small quiz of 6 to 10 problems. I have a test paper created in using exam class. as below. But how do I add it in my memoir class book post every section.

```
    \documentclass[compose,addpoints,12pt,answers]{exam}
\pointname{ M}
\boxedpoints % puts a box around.
\pointsinmargin %this puts on the left margin.
\begin{document}

%Title
    \begin{center}
          \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
                Answer the questions in the spaces provided on the
                question sheets.  If you run out of room for an answer,
                continue on the back of the page. This exam has \numquestions\ questions, for a total of \numpoints\ marks.
           }

          }}

    \end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Student Name :\enspace\hrulefill}
\vspace{0.2in}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Batch :\enspace\hrulefill}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{LMOP}{\bfseries\Large Similarity Quiz 1(GSQ1)}{28 Nov.2018 }
\runningheader{Math 115}
              {First Exam, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
              {July 4, 1776}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{}{}    

% Print or noprint solutions
\printanswers
%\noprintanswers


\begin{questions}   
\question[10]
    Why is there air?
\question
    What if there were no air?
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5]
        Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
        \part[5]
        Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
    \end{parts}

\question[20]
    \begin{parts}
        \part
        Define the universe.  Give three examples.
        \part

        If the universe were to end, how would you know?
    \end{parts}

\question[10] This is a multiple type question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one choice
            \CorrectChoice second choice    
        \end{choices}

\question[5] How many similar triangles are there if altitudes are drawn in a triangle and foot of altitudes are joined. 
    \answerline[6]

\question[10] This is a subjective question
    \begin{solution}
        this is solution    
    \end{solution}



%checkboxes environment
\question[15] This is a check box env \\
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice this 
        \choice second
        \CorrectChoice right one    
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{questions} 

\begin{center}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image: Output of above code.]

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: A class defines the overall look of a document. Thus `memoir.cls' and `exam.cls` specify (possibly clashing) views of the resulting document.  If you want to use `memoir` as the overiding document style then perhaps make the relevant parts of `exam.cls` into a package and use that in the `memoir` class document. Others might find such a package useful to use within, say, the `report` or `article` classes.

Comment: You can prepare (compile) the exams and include them with package `pdfpages` to your document ...